# PHP 7.2 move_uploaded_file is giving text `here`, instead of true or false

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, php-5.6, php-7.2

I have this code,

```
move_uploaded_file($filename_upload, '/site/path/out/of/this/project/files/reports/dailyreports/' . $excelname.".".$ext_name);
```

This have to give me true or false. But it returns text 'here'.

I checked file uploads is On, size is 2MB in php config.

What i changed recently:

updated php from 5.6 to 7.2
Migrated aws ec2 from one zone to another.

Its weired, can any one faced this problem?

Debug Tried:

```
   echo 'coming here';exit;
   move_uploaded_file($filename_upload, '/removed/for/security/files/reports/dailyreports/' . $excelname.".".$ext_name);
```

This prints 'coming here'

```
 move_uploaded_file($filename_upload, '/removed/for/security/files/reports/dailyreports/' . $excelname.".".$ext_name);
 echo 'code not comes this place';exit;
```

This prints 'here'

Comment: size is 2MB? Thats not very big

Comment: _updated php from 5.6 to 7.2 Migrated aws ec2 from one zone to another._ So not much you have not changed

Comment: I doubt that `here` is coming from that. Please show more code.

Comment: Why do you need it to give you `true` or `false`? Any non-empty string is truthy, so there's no need to compare it strictly with `true`.

Comment: @Barmar, updated full code. if i put put echo 'test'; exit; before move_upload_file, it show 'test'. if i put after that it shows only 'here'

Comment: As you dont capture the result of the `move_uploaded_file()` what makes you think that has anything to do with the outputting of `here`. Sounds more like the output from a piece of debug code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am calling this function in ajax. In netowork tab it retuns 'here'.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` doesn't echo anything by itself, so it can't be coming from that.

Comment: This script does not have the text `here` anywhere in it

Comment: I suggest you use the "Find in files" feature in your text editor and look for literal "here" strings. It's very likely that you simply forgot to remove a debug statement.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, but i am wondering where it is from. Its weired

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yeah i tried that too.

Comment: msexcel files are bad, don't download use/download them. Export them as CSV and import CSV files, it will remove a lot of complications about parsing datas with php afterwards. The only step where I can see "HERE" is inside your SQL query... I would bet on a ' or " or ` problem at first glance.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you reduce it to a minimal example that prints `here`? Also, be warned that your code is highly vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase  updated what i have debugged before.

Comment: Did you check whether your code contains a overriden alternative of `move_uploaded_file`?

Comment: @NicoHaase Can you let me know how to check that one.

Comment: Search through your code for a definition. If you are using any modern IDE, that could help you, even more if you use a debugger like XDebug to step through the execution of that code

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using phpstorm, when clicking on move_uploaded_file it goes to this function `function move_uploaded_file(string $from, string $to): bool {}`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;
require_once 'php_libs/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';
```

When i removed the above three lines, `here` done.
So it may be because as Nico Haase suggested in comments.